# Telerik RadScheduler vs DevExpress xtraScheduler Winforms

Tags: winforms

which one do you prefer?Which one is easier to customize the appointment form,and crud with it?Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the appointment form for the Telerik RadScheduler is a pretty simple process. You can watch a video of this being done here:
http://tv.telerik.com/watch/winforms/radscheduler/adding-custom-fields-radscheduler-winforms-appointments

As for binding to a database, this is easily accomplished with RadScheduler as well:
http://blogs.telerik.com/robertshoemate/posts/10-04-01/data_binding_with_radscheduler_for_winforms.aspx

Also, for an in-depth look at RadScheduler, I recommend checking out this webinar that focuses specifically on the control:
http://blogs.telerik.com/robertshoemate/posts/10-04-15/introduction_to_radscheduler_for_winforms_webinar.aspx